# Mean, variance and nothing else

Tags: probability-theory

Is there a distribution which has non-zero variance, but all higher central moments being zero? If not, what is the easiest (less technical) way to show that? Does similar result holds if we talk about usual moments, not central ones?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem

Comment: Non-zero variance, but fourth central moment equal to zero? Well...

Comment: @Did: sounds like 4th central moment is a variance plus some non-negative number?

Comment: Ilya, by Lyapunov $E(X^{2m})\ge (E(X^2))^m \ge (\operatorname{Var}(X))^m$ for $m\ge 1$. Maybe you meant cumulants, not moments? Then you should look at the centered normal distribution.

Comment: @zhoraster: for the cumulants indeed normal distribution has all of them zero besides the first two, so I wondered whether it is possible for central moments. The only thing I could think of is inverting the MGT, but I guessed there is an easier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E[(X - E[X])^4] = 0$, then $(X - E[X])^4 = 0$ almost surely, since the integral of a nonnegative function can only be zero if the function is almost surely zero. This implies $X - E[X] = 0$ almost surely, i.e. $X$ is constant. But a constant random variable has a variance of zero.

In the same fashion $E[X^4] = 0$ implies $X = 0$ almost surely.

Comment: Very simple indeed, thanks